# How can I count the number of orders per customer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have two TABLES as **customers$** and **orders$** (I am not sure why there is a $ sign after the table name. It appears in my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio every time I import the excel file).

customer$ table has 2 columns = name(nvarchar(255,null) | customer_id(float,null)

orders$ table has 4 columns = order_id(nvarchar(255,null) | customer_id | status(nvarchar(255,null) | order_date(datetime, null)

**My statement is to count the number of orders per customer**

```
SELECT c.name,c.customer_id AS CustomerID,o.customer_id AS OcustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_orders
FROM customers$ c, orders$ o
WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY Number_of_orders
```

OUTPUT:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'customers$.customer_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Fyi `tablename$` is the default naming from Excel if you don't **specify** a target table - in Excel the default sheet name is `Sheet1$`

Comment: Did you read the words in the error message? It's pretty clear and direct to the point: **Column 'customers$.customer_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause** can't be any clearer and self-explanatory. It both tells you what the problem is and **exactly** how to fix it in the portion I quoted.

Comment: [Bad habbits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 2):

When you use an aggregate function (like `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc.), any field that is not aggregated must be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT     c.name, c.customer_id AS CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_orders
FROM       customers$ c
INNER JOIN orders$    o  ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE      c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY   c.name, c.customer_id
ORDER BY   Number_of_orders
```

You also don't need `o.customer_id`. The join condition make sure that `c.customer_id` and `o.customer_id` are identical.

Also, avoid the old join syntax:

```sql
FROM  tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.column = tableB.column
```

Replace it with `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
FROM       tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.column = tableB.column
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeDifferent . It helped.  I tried to show an average number of products each customer had on their orders.
SELECT DISTINCT(c.customer_id) AS CustomerID, o.order_id AS OrderID, COUNT(o.product_id) NumOfOrders, c.order_date AS OrderDate, 
AVG(o.product_id)AS AvgProductOrdered
FROM orders$ c
JOIN ['order items$'] o ON c.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE c.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, o.order_id, order_date
ORDER BY AvgProductOrdered DESC

OUTPUT: Shows similar customer id in the customer_id list including others even though I used DISTINCT clause. Is that correct way

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do either an in-line select

```
SELECT c.name,c.customer_id AS CustomerID, (select COUNT(*) FROM orders$ o c.customer_id = o.customer_id) AS Number_of_orders
ORDER BY Number_of_orders
```

or you need to add c.customer_id to your Group By. Also no point in selecting o.Customer_id as that should be identical to c.customer_id

```
SELECT c.name,c.customer_id AS CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_orders
FROM customers$ c, orders$ o
WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY name, c.customer_id
ORDER BY Number_of_order
```